# How long does Infura store a file on IPFS?

Tags: ipfs, infura

You can send files to Infura's IPFS servers but I don't know about the limits.

How long is it stored for?

What's the size limit?

Comment: I see some people voted to close this question. I am wondering what is the reason for it

Comment: I checked and it seems to be offtopic, however there are tags specifically for "infura" and "ipfs" so does that mean the tags are offtopic also?

Comment: I voted to close the question - Infura and IPFS are third-party products. If you had asked how to use them with Ethereum or something like that it would've been ok. Well, this is just my opinion, that's why these are being voted on. I'd also say the tags are ok if used in a scenario which I just described.

Comment: When I post about IPFS I am told it is off-topic. Double standards are great.

Comment: @TrevorOakley I read the comment and I agree it makes sense. Infura is a 3rd party and probably the question should be removed. However Infura and IPFS are very often used with Ethereum and while the question is not about Ethereum specifically, it is very closely related to it.

Comment: @cleanunicorn but my question was stopped about IPFS and hence I said double standards. It looks like people are saying someone with a high reputation can post about IPFS and someone else who has a lower reputation cannot. That is my issue: one standard for us both.

Comment: If infura helps to access to ipfs node, who will pay for the hard disk and bandwidth for file storage, even for redundancy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got a reply from an Infura member.

At the moment if you pin objects on their nodes they won't be removed. Unpinned objects are garbage collected when the data store needs to reclaim space.

File size is not explicitly limited but you might encounter gateway timeout for very large files.

Answer (score 3):

While developing a dApp using the infura gateway to ipfs we noticed that files are being removed after ~2 weeks.

I also just did some research there and am pretty sure that I read exactly that somewhere but I can't seem to find the resource anymore...

To overcome the issue of files being removed you can just regularly pin them on a local node to keep them up.

Unfortunately I have no info about file sizes.

Comment: If you pin your file at Infura's IPFS endpoint, it won't be removed.

Comment: Maybe I am doing something wrong - but for us Files unfortunately disappear

Comment: In that case, please file a ticket https://infura.io/support/ticket

Answer (score 1):

Just adding more to the answer by @kai-kälberer.

I recommend using the `ipfs-mini` javascript library when writing to ipfs. They have automatic pinning built in, which will allow your ipfs files to persist longer.

Here is a code example of Reading and Writing to IPFS supported by Infura.

```
import IPFS from 'ipfs-mini'
import isString from 'lodash/fp/isString'

const ipfs = new IPFS({ host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' })

export async function ipfsGetData (multihash) {
  if (!isString(multihash)) {
    return new Error('multihash must be String')
  } else if (!multihash.startsWith('Qm')) {
    return new Error('multihash must start with "Qm"')
  }

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipfs.catJSON(multihash, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(new Error(err))
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
}

export async function ipfsAddObject (obj) {
  const CID = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ipfs.addJSON(obj, (err, result) => {
      if (err) reject(new Error(err))
      resolve(result)
    })
  })
  console.log('CID:', CID)
  return CID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to this recent post by Infura on September 23, 2020:
https://blog.infura.io/part-2-getting-started-with-ipfs-on-infura/

> Data is currently pinned until it’s been 6 months since it was last used, so as long as you’re accessing your data within that time frame, it’ll be there for you!