# Can IPFS protect privacy?

Tags: ipfs

I understand IPFS is public by design but can a record be placed in IPFS which is accessible only by the owners? Or accessible and readable (but excluding encryption solutions).

Edit - 
This site has many references to IPFS which were not put on hold - eg [How long does Infura store a file on IPFS?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46638/how-long-does-infura-store-a-file-on-ipfs)

Comment: It is not directly about ethereum but ethereum is seen as a means to store hashes about ipfs data structures. Also this site has many references to IPFS eg https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46638/how-long-does-infura-store-a-file-on-ipfs and that person was allowed his question and he is an experienced user. So you are basically discriminating based on reputation and not content.

Answer (score 0):

You can protect privacy with encryption.
Encrypt a file with someone else’s public key
Add it to ipfs. Dont forget to encrypt data before adding it to ipfs.
For encryption you can use GPG.

This prevent non authorized users to read file, but not prevent nodes to redistribute content(which is encrypted).

Also you can disconnect your ipfs daemon from all peers an connect only to nodes you are interested in. Config file allows you to start ipfs daemon without connected peers, than you can manually connect to node you want.